# Convergence of $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\log n(\log\log n)^\alpha} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

> Does the following series converge: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\log n(\log\log n)^\alpha} $ and $\alpha>0$ ?

Using Cauchy condensation test twice:

$\begin{align} \displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{3^n}{3^n\log 3^n(\log\log 3^n)^\alpha} &= \displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\log 3(\log(n\log 3)^\alpha} \\ &=
\displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{3^n}{3^n\log 3(\log(3^n\log 3)^\alpha} \\ &= 
\displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\log (3) (n\log(3\log 3)^\alpha}\end {align}$

So the series converges iff $\alpha >1$ and diverges otherwise like the harmonic series.

Comment: There's a parenthesis missing. What does the $\alpha$ exponentiate?

Comment: @DanielFischer fixed.

Comment: That works. Integral test works even faster.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I can't use it...

Comment: @GinKin $u=\log\log x, du= \frac{dx}{x \log x}$.

Comment: That works, but if you write it down for real, do not equate the condensed series with the uncondensed one as you did in the second equality sign.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490309/sum-frac1n-log-n-sum-frac1n-log-n-log-log-n-etc-diverge-wh