# $\sum \frac{1}{n \log n}, \sum \frac{1}{n \log n \log \log n},$ etc. diverge. What about $\frac{1}{n (\log n)^{1 + \varepsilon}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

It is a well-known fact that $\displaystyle \sum \frac{1}{n \log n}, \sum \frac{1}{n \log n \log \log n},$ and so forth diverge. Indeed, by the integral test, they are given by the anti derivative $\log ( \log( \dots \log (n)\dots))$.

What can be said about the convergence of $\sum \frac{1}{n (\log n)^{1 + \varepsilon}}$, for each $\varepsilon > 0$? And also such series as $\sum\frac{1}{n \log n (\log \log n)^{1 + \varepsilon}}$, etc.?

I have a feeling that they converge, but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Hint: Use the Cauchy condensation test.

Comment: @C.I.J. So we get $\sum \frac{1}{(n \log 2)^{1 + \varepsilon}}$ which converges by $p$-test. Nice.

Comment: Alternatively, just use the integral test: $$\int \frac{dx}{x(\log x)^{1+\epsilon}} = \frac{-1}{\epsilon(\log x)^\epsilon}+C$$ and so on.

Comment: \For $\epsilon=1,2,3$ numerical results of $\sum_n 1/[n \log n (\log \log n)^{1+\epsilon}]$ are in https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.0789

Comment: See also https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Bertrand .